# Google Apps Script JQuery Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I have a form that I want to popup in Google Sheets.  I am using the script editor to achieve this but for some reason this is not working

```
  <html>
  <body>


<form action="">
 <input id='DP' type="text" class="form-control formBlock" name="maxDP"  placeholder="Max DP Amount . . ." required/><br />
 <input id='cost' type="text" class="form-control formBlock" name="cost"  placeholder="Cost . . ." required/><br />
 <input id='finFee' type="text" class="form-control formBlock" name="financeFee"  placeholder="Finance Fee . . ." required/><br />
 <input id='rqComm' type="hidden" class="form-control formBlock" name="rqComm"  placeholder="RQ Commission . . ." required/><br />
<br /><br />
Total GP: <span id="total_gp"></span>
<br />



</form>


<script>

$('input').keyup(function(){ 

    var maxDP  = Number($('#DP').val());  

    var rqComm = Number($('130').val()); 

    var cost  = Number($('#cost').val());

    var financeFee = Number($('#finFee').val());

    $('#total_gp').html(maxDP + rqComm - cost - financeFee); 
});

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The above does not output any data.  It should work on keyup from my understanding of JS.

What seems to be wrong with this javascript?

I was able to figure out how to get this to work.  I had changed one of the lines in the JS to 130.  This was trying to call that field but broke my script.  I added a value to the form and changed the JS to reflect this and all is working now.  Below is my script
Working Script

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<input id='dpMax' type="text" class="form-control formBlock" name="bus_ticket"  placeholder="DP Max..." required/>

<input id='cost' type="text" class="form-control formBlock" name="plane_ticket"  placeholder="Cost..." required/>

<input id='fee' type="text" class="form-control formBlock" name="hotel_expenses"  placeholder="5% Fee..." required/>

<input id='rqComm' type="hidden" class="form-control formBlock" name="eating_expenses" value="130"  placeholder="RQ Commisson..." required/>
<br />
Total: <span id="total_expenses1"></span>


<br /><br />


</body>
<script>
$('input').keyup(function(){ 
var dpMax  = Number($('#dpMax').val());   
var cost = Number($('#cost').val()); 
var fee  = Number($('#fee').val());
var rqComm = Number($('#rqComm').val());

$('#total_expenses1').html(dpMax + cost + fee + rqComm); // add them and output it
document.getElementById('total_expenses2').value = dpMax + cost + fee + rqComm; });

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery library is not loaded. Add smth like:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/core.js"></script>
```

Prior to scripts utilizing jQuery.

P.S. always check browser console for errors.

Comment: I tried your recommended solution but this did not work for me.  I also ran the debugger and I get no errors with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue by fixing the line

```
var rqComm = Number($('130').val());
```

This was trying to find the form input 130 which did no exist.

full working script

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<input id='dpMax' type="text" class="form-control formBlock" name="bus_ticket"  placeholder="DP Max..." required/>

<input id='cost' type="text" class="form-control formBlock" name="plane_ticket"  placeholder="Cost..." required/>

<input id='fee' type="text" class="form-control formBlock" name="hotel_expenses"  placeholder="5% Fee..." required/>

<input id='rqComm' type="hidden" class="form-control formBlock" name="eating_expenses" value="130"  placeholder="RQ Commisson..." required/>
<br />
Total: <span id="total_expenses1"></span>


<br /><br />


</body>
<script>
$('input').keyup(function(){ 
var dpMax  = Number($('#dpMax').val());   
var cost = Number($('#cost').val()); 
var fee  = Number($('#fee').val());
var rqComm = Number($('#rqComm').val());

$('#total_expenses1').html(dpMax + cost + fee + rqComm); // add them and output it
document.getElementById('total_expenses2').value = dpMax + cost + fee + rqComm; });

</script>
</html>
```

I also added the jquery library to the head which corrected some of my issue as well thanks to one of the answers.